# getMongoOperations method removed from SimpleMongoRepository Spring Data MongoDB Core without any trace

Tags: dependencies, spring-data-mongodb

We are upgrading our dependencies, and we went from Spring Data MongoDB Core 1.6.0.RELEASE to Spring Data MongoDB Core 1.10.4.RELEASE there seems to be no getMongoOperations() in the SimpleMongoRepository as of version 1.6.2. and the javadoc does not say anything and google isn't really helping much either. Was it moved, omitted, depricated?

We are using the getMongoOperations in a bunch of places to return data like this.

```
@Override
public List<Employee> findAllByCompanyId(String companyId) {
    Criteria criteria = Criteria.where("companyId").is(companyId);

    return getMongoOperations().find(new Query(criteria), Employee.class);
}
```

Comment: What are you doing after getting `MongoOperations` from `SimpleMongoRepositoty` ? This pull request has that change. https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-mongodb/pull/253

Comment: its beeing used for returning data, the original post was edited.

Comment: You can always autowire the Mongo Template bean